# Does forwarding e-mails to Tuta through Gmail compromise privacy no matter what?

Tags: gmail, tutanota

I am using e-mail forwarding from Gmail to a tuta address (e-mail service with encryption) with 'delete Gmail's copy option'. Does that mean, that e-mails that get to my tuta inbox through Gmail are *de facto* compromised, since they come from Google to Tuta?

Is there anything I can do about it (other than not having e-mails go through Google first, of course)

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

Only messages between Tuta users are encrypted end-to-end.

Any Tuta messages that you send to, or receive from, non-Tuta addresses are unencrypted in transit, and only encrypted while on Tuta's servers. That would of course include messages you forward yourself from Gmail and those you send to Gmail recipients.